# ejabberd group chat configuration with muc

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ubuntu-server, multiuserchat, ejabberd-module

I installed and configured the `ejabberd2` server on my `ubuntu server`
and i `mod_muc` is enabled by default, but i can't able to group chat through the `XMPP Client App AstraChat` in `Android` and `iOS`
Group Created successfully, but the group members doesn't receive the messages
I searched google for this, i found that `muc_admin` mod is required, when i enabled it and restarted the ejabberd it shows `ejabberd started`, but it is not started

can anybody help me to figure out what is the problem with the configuration

Answer (score 0):

muc_admin module is not required to use XMPP MUC room in ejabberd. This is a module to enable command-line API to manage MUC room for admins.

However, from an XMPP client, you can still use MUC room normally. You can test with Psi Web client, as it allows MUC room configuration. It may help you understand and troubleshoot your usage query.

Comment: Thank you, i will check and get back to you